# I want my Input to be visible in the next line once I click on Submit Button :: React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, event-handling, dom-events

I am unable to print the Input-
Problem- I give an input and click on the button. I want the input to be visible in the next line.

react

```
import React from 'react';

class NameForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {value: ''};
  
      this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }
  
    handleChange(event) {
    event.preventDefault()  
    this.setState({value: event.target.value})      
      
    }
  
    render() {
      return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit= {this.handleChange}>
         
         <input type="text"/>
          
          <button>Submit</button>
        </form>
        
        <h1>{this.state.value}</h1>
        </div>
      )
    }
  }
 
export default NameForm;
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Your passing change handler to submit, this won't work.
2. You have to keep track of the inputs with state the way I did or you can use Refs to get the values of the inputs.

Your issue could be solved like this

```
import React from "react";

class NameForm extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { value: "", show: false };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
 }

 handleChange(event) {
    //keep track of input changes 
    this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
 }

 handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ show: true });
    // handle form submission here
 }

 render() {
     return (
         <div>
              <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                  <input onChange={this.handleChange} type="text" />

                  <button>Submit</button>
              </form>

              {this.state.show ? (
                   <div>
                      <h1>{this.state.value}</h1>
                   </div>
               ) : null}
         </div>
    );
  }
}

export default NameForm;
```

Comment: The input is being displayed even without a button click. With the above code.

Comment: you can add check to prevent **onChange** function.

Comment: I have updated the code to render the input only after submiting the form.